# Counterexamples in Laplace transforms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, laplace-transform, analytic-continuation

Of all the examples I know of (bilateral) Laplace transforms $F$ defined on their maximal vertical strips $V_{a,b}=\{ z \in \mathbf{C} : a < \operatorname{Re}(z) < b \}$ with $-\infty < a < b \leq + \infty$ either two things happens at the boundary:

1. The function $F$ has a pole on the line $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$ and in some cases has another (different determining function) Laplace representation for some $a' < \operatorname{Re}(z) < a$ (take for instance the Gamma function with poles at every negative integer)
2. The function does not have a singularity at $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$ and may even have an analytic continuation beyond the maximal strip. Take for instance the Laplace transform of $f(t)= \pi e^t \sin(\pi e^t)$, whose Laplace transform $F(z)$ has $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ as its half-plane of convergence, but $F(z)$ has an analytic continuation to all of the complex plane (see Doetsch book on the Laplace transform for details)

My question is: Can we construct a function $F(z)$ which is a bilateral Laplace transform on some vertical strip $V_{a,b}$, loses its integral representation at $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$ without losing analyticity, and then can be written again as a Laplace transform on an adjacent strip $V_{u,a}$?

If so, how are the determining functions related on the adjacent strips?